# Gurobi Optimization Result Writing into Csv file

Tags: optimization, export-to-csv, linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am using Gurobi 7 to solve my MIP. I have several different variables. However, I am specifically interested in two of those, "x" and "y" namely. For the reference, I am giving my code that shows how I added x and y variables into the solver:

```
# Creating Variables
x = {}
y = {}

# Adding Variables
for i in range(I):
    x[i+1,P[i]-d[0]] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s" % str([i+1,P[i]-d[0]]))
    x[i+1,P[i]] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x%s" % str([i+1,P[i]]))
for i in range(I):
    for k in range(len(rangevalue)):
        y[i+1, rangevalue[k] - E[i]] = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,
                               name="y%s" % str([i+1, rangevalue[k] - E[i]]))
```

Even though the above code may not really make any sense, I just wanted to show it in case you may use it for my problem.

After I solve the problem, I get the following results:

`m.printAttr('X')`

```
    Variable            X 
-------------------------
     x[1, 3]            1 
sigmaminus[1]          874 
     x[2, 2]            1 
sigmaminus[2]         1010 
     x[3, 2]            1 
sigmaminus[3]         1945 
     x[4, 4]            1 
sigmaplus[4]           75 
     x[5, 4]            1 
sigmaminus[5]         1153 
     x[6, 5]            1 
sigmaminus[6]          280 
     x[7, 3]            1 
sigmaplus[7]         1138 
     x[8, 2]            1 
sigmaplus[8]          538 
     x[9, 1]            1 
sigmaplus[9]         2432 
    x[10, 5]            1 
sigmaminus[10]          480 
    omega[1]           12 
    OMEGA[1]           12 
    omega[2]            9 
    OMEGA[2]           12 
    omega[3]            8 
    OMEGA[3]            9 
    omega[4]            8 
    OMEGA[4]            8 
    OMEGA[5]            8 
     y[1, 2]            1 
     y[2, 9]            1 
     y[3, 5]            1 
     y[4, 6]            1 
     y[5, 4]            1 
     y[6, 6]            1 
     y[7, 3]            1 
    y[8, 11]            1 
     y[9, 8]            1 
    y[10, 1]            1 
  phiplus[6]            1 
 phiminus[7]            1 
phiminus[10]            1
```

I specifically want to display x and y variables with their indexes. Other variables are not necessary. My question is how can I write these results into an csv file on one column as following?

```
x[1,3]
x[2,2]
x[3,2]
.
.
.
x[10,5]
y[1,2]
y[2,9]
y[3,5]
.
.
.
y[10,1]
```

I do not need their corresponding value which can only be "1" since they are binary variables. I just need to write the variables which have the value "1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
import csv

if m.SolCount == 0:
    print("Model has no solution")
    exit(1)

var_names = []    

for var in m.getVars():
    # Or use list comprehensions instead 
    if 'x' == str(var.VarName[0]) and var.X > 0.1:
        var_names.append(var.VarName)

# Write to csv
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
     wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     wr.writerows(var_names)
```

I hope this helps.  <s>I am going to test this snippet a bit later.</s> **Update**: works as intended.

Comment: I kind of get what you are doing, but it really does not work in my case. Well, I am checking for feasibility; the problem is feasible and yielding an answer. Should I change anything on var.VarName[0]?

Comment: I just checked my code again and it seems I am using `str(var.VarName[0])`. Could you give it a go? Make sure you compare to a lower case `'x'`

Comment: with this: `wr.writerows(zip(var_names))`, it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad that it works! I am wondering why it is necessary to `zip` the `var_names`. Does it fail without it?

Comment: It splits everything into columns e.g.:
`x        [          1        ,          2       ]` I mean, everything goes into one cell. Hope I could clarify.